I don't understand where the number 35 MW comes from
I don't understand where the number 35 MW comes from.

Thanks for your answer.

260 - (75*3) = 35

Total system load given in a) is 260 MW. Other three generators are supplying 75 MW each. 75 x 3 = 225 MW. The difference is 260 - 225 = 35 MW.

Total system load is 260MW at start, with generators 1-3 supplying 75MW each.
Load on generator 4 is 260-3*75=35MW
